# custom height gridview in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I do my flutter app.How can i do grid view with custom height and wight in flutter?Item in grid view should be as a rectangle but not a square.

[image]

Comment: Add an example code of what you have tried so we can help you, maybe a [dartpad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with childAspectRatio. I have made clear with an example below for landscape and portrait mode as well. If you want a square grid, then consider using childAspectRatio as 1.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> cities = ['Kathmandu', 'Baglung', 'Pokhara'];
  var width = 100;
  var height = 200;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: cities.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation ==
                          Orientation.landscape ? 3: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                  childAspectRatio: width / height),
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Text(
                    cities[position],
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-) plugin.

CODE:

```
class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _MyHomeScreenState createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();
  }

class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {

List<ItemDetailsModel> itemDetails = [
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 1",
      color: Colors.teal
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello  2",
      color: Colors.teal[100]
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 3",
      color: Colors.teal[200]
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 4",
      color: Colors.teal[300]
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 5",
      color: Colors.teal
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 6",
      color: Colors.tealAccent
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 7",
      color: Colors.tealAccent[200]
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 8",
      color: Colors.tealAccent[300]
    ),
    ItemDetailsModel(
      name: "Hello 9",
      color: Colors.green
    ),


  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Staggered Grid View"),),
      body: Center(
        child: sliverGridWidget(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget sliverGridWidget(BuildContext context){
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemCount: itemDetails.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Container(
            color:itemDetails[index].color,
             child:Text(itemDetails[index].name)
          );
        },
         staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.count(2,3), //Make size as you want.
         mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
         crossAxisSpacing:8.0,
      );
  }
}
```

Model class:

```
class ItemDetailsModel{
  String name;
  Color color;
  ItemDetailsModel({this.name, this.color});
}
```

Output:

[image]